# Equivalent Python3 code to JS DES encryption with CryptoJS

Tags: python-3.x, cryptojs

I have a js DES encryption code uses CryptoJS as below:

```js
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

function encryptByDES(message, key) {
        var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return encrypted.toString();
      }
```

and if input `message="123456789", key="123456abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, the output is `J6cwLeYoidP5U1V6MT67Ig==`.

I want to know the Python3 version of the code. I trid [PyCrytodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des.html?highlight=DES) with no luck ( I'm not much understand this package), recent code is as below:

```py
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import binascii

data = b'123456789'
key = b'123456abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
iv = get_random_bytes(16)
# below line triggers error
cipher1 = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_CFB, iv)
ct = cipher1.encrypt(pad(data, 16))
print(binascii.b2a_base64(ct))
```

the error is

```sh
ValueError: Incorrect DES key length (32 bytes)
```

please help me out.

Comment: PyCryptodome expects an 8 bytes key for DES. CryptoJS implicitly truncates too long keys, with PyCryptpdome this must be done explicitly. Furthermore, in the CryptoJS code the ECB mode (and not the CFB mode) is used which doesn't apply an IV. When padding, the block size of DES must be used, which is 8 bytes. Please note, DES and ECB are both insecure.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco . I've solve the problem now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Topaco's suggestion, finally it's working, the code is as below:

```py
data = b'123456789'
# the next cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz is no needed
key = b'123456ab'
cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
ct = cipher.encrypt(pad(data, 8))
print(binascii.b2a_base64(ct))
```

FYI.

Comment: It should be `pad(data, 8)` instead of `pad(data, 16)`, so that it's padded to a multiple of the DES block size (8 bytes). For the plaintext `b'123456789'` this has no effect, but e.g. for the plaintext `b'1234567'` as can be easily verified by a comparison with the result of the CryptoJS code.